# Cuda cannot run more than 1024*255 Threads

Tags: c++, cuda, thrust

I am running on Amazon's K520 GPU with 1500 cores and 4GB RAM.  I am trying the run a kernel with 1024*850 threads.  I know I can only get up to 1024 threads per block, but it surprised me when I could not launch more than 255 blocks using 1024 threads per block (I get a launch error).  I thought the limit was 2^16 for grid sizes.  When I ran an empty kernel though, it goes through it fine.  That makes me think there is not enough memory somewhere.  I wonder if I could get an explanation as to what is happening.  Thanks.  Here is the kernel:

```
__global__ void dotSubCentroidNorm
(
 Pt* segments,
 int pointCount,
 const Pt* centroids,
 const int* segmentChanges,
 float *dotResult
 )
{

  int idx = index();
  if(idx>=pointCount)
    return;
  int segment = segments[idx].segmentIndex;
  if(segment<0)
    return;
  int segPtCount = segmentChanges[segment+1]-segmentChanges[segment];
  Pt &pt = segments[idx];
  if(segPtCount==0)
  {
    printf("segment pt count =0 %d %d\n",idx, segment);
    return;
  }
  const Pt &ctr = centroids[segment];
  pt.x=pt.x-ctr.x/segPtCount;
  pt.y=pt.y-ctr.y/segPtCount;
  pt.z=pt.z-ctr.z/segPtCount;

  dotResult[idx] = pt.x*pt.x;
  dotResult[pointCount + idx] = pt.x*pt.y;
  dotResult[pointCount*2 + idx] = pt.x*pt.z;
  dotResult[pointCount*3 + idx] = pt.y*pt.y;
  dotResult[pointCount*4 + idx] = pt.y*pt.z;
  dotResult[pointCount*5 + idx] = pt.z*pt.z;
}
```

and the struct:

```
struct Pt
{
  float x,y,z;
  int segmentIndex;
};
```

I am calling this kernel with an array of about 400,000 Pt's for segments, and 200 Pt's for centroids, and 200 for segmentChanges, and 400,000*6 for dotResult.  Here is the call:

```
....
thrust::device_vector<float> dotResult(pointCount*6);

printf("Errors1: %s \n",cudaGetErrorString(cudaGetLastError()));

int tpb = 1024; //threads per block
dim3 blocks = blkCnt(pointCount, tpb);
printf("blocks: %d %d\n", blocks.x, blocks.y);
dotSubCentroidNorm<<<blocks ,tpb>>>
  (
   segments,
   pointCount,
   thrust::raw_pointer_cast(centroids.data()),
   segmentChanges,
   thrust::raw_pointer_cast(dotResult.data())
  );
printf("Errors2: %s \n",cudaGetErrorString(cudaGetLastError()));
cudaThreadSynchronize();

printf("Errors3: %s \n",cudaGetErrorString(cudaGetLastError()));
....

 #define blkCnt(size, threadsPerBlock) dim3(min(255,(int)floor(1+(size)/(threadsPerBlock))),floor(1+(size)/(threadsPerBlock)/256))
#define index() (threadIdx.x + (((gridDim.x * blockIdx.y) + blockIdx.x)*blockDim.x))
....
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Why do I get an error when I launch more than 1024*255 threads of this kernel?

Comment: It's better if you provide a short, complete code that someone else can copy, compile and run. Yes, it requires some work on your part, but it makes for more effective help.   What is the exact error message you are receiving?  What is the value of `pointCount`?  (yes, you provided a bunch of numbers, I can't tell which one of them is actually `pointCount`.  A complete code would have made it obvious.)  What happens when you run your code with `cuda-memcheck` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So apparently I was passing in a host array for "segmentChanges" instead of a device, which is why it was crashing.